# stringify objects within an array but not the array itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping my arrays (there's quite a bit). So the idea is to just stringify all objects/everything within the array.

```
  const studentInfoObj = students.map(value => (
      // for each student return json string of the objects
      // how can I just stringify everything within the array?
      // but not the array itself. Just all the objects inside?
      return JSON.stringify(???);
  ));
```

Here's the json currently so s

```
{"Michael00043":
     // stringify from this point
     [
          {"student_num":"20293290000HJ93",
           "campus":"McHale",
           "major":"PSI"
          },
     ],
      ... more objects
     [
          {"medical_doc":"st.laurance hos",
           "emergency_contact":"Adam Harley",
           "blood_type":"O"
          },
          {"hospital":"st.laurance hos",
           "ward":"B",
          },
     ]
...
```

Comment: your solution is right. what do you want?

Comment: Your JSON is badly formatted. Can you please give a valid example. You have a start `[` but no close `]`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan yeah sorry it definitely is. It's extremely long. I just tried to post a simple example of it.

Comment: @rishabhdev well i'm just trying to figure out what to stringify. if i return JSON.stringify(value); it just prints out "Michael00043".. But I'm trying to stringify everything within Michael00043/student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
var students = {
  "Michael00043": [{
    "student_num": "20293290000HJ93",
    "campus": "McHale",
    "major": "PSI"
  }, {
    "medical_doc": "st.laurance hos",
    "emergency_contact": "Adam Harley",
    "blood_type": "O"
  }]


};

// loop through each student
for (student in students) {
  // stringy each value in the array that each student is
  students[student] = students[student].map(value => JSON.stringify(value));
}

console.log(students);
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. I'm just having a hard time with jsx syntax